# Bad orocos_kdl version with robot_state_publisher

Tags: ros, deb, ros-hydro, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seeing this on a Hydro install:

```
process[robot_state_publisher-7]: started with pid [17121]
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/robot_state_publisher/state_publisher: error while loading shared libraries: liborocos-kdl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
No handlers could be found for logger "roslaunch"
[robot_state_publisher-7] process has died [pid 17121, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/robot_state_publisher/state_publisher __name:=robot_state_publisher __log:=/tmp/8ca25758-d179-11e3-85e3-0001c0118a71/robot_state_publisher-7.log].
log file: /tmp/8ca25758-d179-11e3-85e3-0001c0118a71/robot_state_publisher-7*.log
```

Both ros-hydro-orocos-kdl and ros-hydro-robot-state-publisher claim to be up-to-date, so I'm not quite sure what's going on.

```
$ ls -1 /opt/ros/hydro/lib/liboroco*
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/liborocos-bfl.so
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/liborocos-kdl.so
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/liborocos-kdl.so.1.2
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/liborocos-kdl.so.1.2.1
$ sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-robot-state-publisher
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
ros-hydro-robot-state-publisher is already the newest version.
```

Thoughts what's going on here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/159571/bad-orocos_kdl-version-with-robot_state_publisher/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1153 on 2014-05-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is the same error that is described in [robot_state_publisher issue #11](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/issues/11). You might want to check the versions you´re using with the commands stated there. I remember encountering this problem a few months ago, too. But updating packages has since fixed it for me.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0